# Print the two matched variables of awk in same line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

This is the script which i wrote.

```
Date=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')

for i in `awk -F"[.: ]" '/start/{start=($4 * 3600) + ($5 * 60) + $6;date=$4$5} /end/{print date;print (($4 * 3600) + ($5 * 60) + $6)-start;start=""}' logs.txt`;  do
    echo "$i"
done
```

The logs.txt consists of :

```
11.04.2018 09:21:35 aaaaa: start_time
11.04.2018 09:22:35 aaaaa: end_time
11.04.2018 10:45:00 aaaaa: start_time
11.04.2018 11:00:00 aaaaa: end_time
```

In this the expected output is :

```
2018-04-11 09:21:35,60
2018-04-11 10:45:00,900
```

But the output i am getting is :

```
2018-04-13,0921
2018-04-13,60
2018-04-13,1045
2018-04-13,900
```

Can anyone rectify what is the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thinks this problem should be separated multiple problems.
How do you think about below code?

```
# extract records: log file may contain other informations
awk '$4=="start_time";$4=="end_time"' logs.txt  |
# wrap records:
# # start_time and end_time may appear alternately in the log.
# # wrap a pair into 1 line.
awk '{if(NR%2==1){ printf("%s ",$0) }else{ print }}'    |
# and convert
# # tr command character wise editor, read ``man tr''.
tr '.:' ' ' |
# # make your favorite output
awk -v OFS="," '{
    print $3 "-" $2 "-" $1 " " $4 ":" $5 ":" $6,
    3600 * ($12-$4) + 60 * ($13-$5) + ($14-$6)
    }'
```

You can see what these code actually do by increment piped commands, as shown below:

```
$ awk '$4=="start_time";$4=="end_time"' logs.txt
11.04.2018 09:21:35 aaaaa: start_time
11.04.2018 09:22:35 aaaaa: end_time
11.04.2018 10:45:00 aaaaa: start_time
11.04.2018 11:00:00 aaaaa: end_time
$ awk '$4=="start_time";$4=="end_time"' logs.txt    |
> awk '{if(NR%2==1){ printf("%s ",$0) }else{ print }}'
11.04.2018 09:21:35 aaaaa: start_time 11.04.2018 09:22:35 aaaaa: end_time
11.04.2018 10:45:00 aaaaa: start_time 11.04.2018 11:00:00 aaaaa: end_time
$ awk '$4=="start_time";$4=="end_time"' logs.txt    |
> awk '{if(NR%2==1){ printf("%s ",$0) }else{ print }}'  |
> tr '.:' ' '
11 04 2018 09 21 35 aaaaa  start_time 11 04 2018 09 22 35 aaaaa  end_time
11 04 2018 10 45 00 aaaaa  start_time 11 04 2018 11 00 00 aaaaa  end_time
$ awk '$4=="start_time";$4=="end_time"' logs.txt    |
> awk '{if(NR%2==1){ printf("%s ",$0) }else{ print }}'  |
> tr '.:' ' '   |
> awk -v OFS="," '{
>   print $3 "-" $2 "-" $1 " " $4 ":" $5 ":" $6,
>       3600 * ($12-$4) + 60 * ($13-$5) + ($14-$6)
>   }'
2018-04-11 09:21:35,60
2018-04-11 10:45:00,900
```

Comment: Yeah it works . Thank you . But can i get an explaination of the code .

Comment: I added explanation. do you need more details?

Comment: Yeah one query i have . What happens  :  (1) If it doesnot have an end_time and (2) When some statements are between start_time and end_time - karnak

Comment: Too bad this is the accepted answer as it's completely wrong. You don't need 3 calls to awk plus a tr and multiple pipes just to do this trivial task and it doesn't take into account leap days, leap seconds, DST, etc. See [@James Brown's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49809321/1745001) for the right approach.

Answer (score 2):

In GNU awk:

```
awk '
{
    split($1 " " $2,a,"[.: ]")                                  # split for mktime
    s=mktime(a[3] " " a[2] " " a[1] " " a[4] " " a[5] " " a[6]) # to secs
    if($4=="end_time")                                          # at end_time
        print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,",p) s-p              # print start time and difference
    p=s                                                         # set secs to prev
}' file
2018-04-11 09:21:35,60
2018-04-11 10:45:00,900
```